# How to track user progress?

Tags: database, users

I'm looking to build a very lightweight learning management system of sorts.  I'll have 2 custom post types "Course" and "Lesson".  I will associate the Lessons to the Courses, probably by using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin.

What I need to do is somehow track whether or not a user has "completed" or "viewed" a specific Lesson. I'll probably add a button that says "Mark as Complete" or something.

The question is, what information should I be saving, and how should I be saving it (when the user clicks the button)?  Further, what table in the DB should this information be saved in?

I see that there are some plugins out there like WP Complete, but it doesn't offer exactly what I need.  I'm open to any ideas/recommendations. Thanks!

Comment: You can use users custom meta with the information of courses or lessons completed. you can use ``update_user_meta($user_id,'lessons_completed','lesson_id')`` or more complicated (lessons ids seperated with comma etc.) . Or Reverse! Add completed_users to lessons or courses custom metas and after that add user ids

Comment: That's a good idea.  I've started down the path of creating a separate table to relate users to lessons, but I'm still open to different/new/better ideas. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ACF you can also attach custom fields to users. You can attach them by using the *Location Rules* (the ones in the 'User' subgroup), see [Creating custom user profile pages with ACF](https://usersinsights.com/acf-user-profile/)

You could add a single *relational → post object* field in a field group, *Filter by Post Type* → *Lesson*.

Then you could use a [front-end form](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/create-a-front-end-form/) which you can pre-populate with that specific lesson (see: [Pre-populate Relationship field...](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/pre-populate-relationship-field-with-default-value-if-not-already-set/)) – then you might also want to hide the input with CSS.